# Shell prompt customization and cmd behavior

Tags: command-line, bashrc, .profile, prompt, ps1

I want my prompt to display:

1. current (absolute) working directory, colored in green and
2. in a NEW line, the dollar sign and an empty space.

I am using this line in `.profile`

`export PS1='\e[0;32m$(pwd)\n\e[m$ '`

So when in e.g. `Desktop`, my prompt looks like this:

[image]

However, sometimes when hitting the up arrow to re-run previous commands, at the start of the prompt a random char sequence appear that does not seem to go away unless I hit enter, e. g.

[image]

I have never hit a `cd cd Desktop` command. The weirdest part is that backspace won't even delete the first one of the two `cd` commands above!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must make sure the non-printing characters in the prompt are in escaped square brackets, otherwise bash cannot calculate the size of the prompt correctly. I think I have fixed it for you:

```
PS1='\[\e[0;32m\]$PWD\n\[\e[m\]$ '
```

Comment: If you use `$PWD` instead of `$(pwd)` the shell doesn't have to set up a pipe, fork two new processes and invoke one external command for every prompt. :-)

Comment: @DavidFoerster haha thanks! It's a while since I messed with my prompt. The proper PS1 way is to use `\w` but it changes `/home/zanna` into `~`

Comment: I know. I wasn't sure either and had to look it up in the manual.

Answer (score 2):

First of all a big thanks to @Zanna for pointing out the correct way to go about this.

For the sake of a more complete answer I have expanded the solution that includes:

a) the cwd in green color

b) in a NEW line, the git branch (if any) in a yellowish color with a red star if the branch is dirty

To accomplish b, the [git aware prompt](https://github.com/jimeh/git-aware-prompt) is necessary

It goes something like this as a final line in **`~/.bashrc`**

```
export PS1='\[\e[0;32m\]$PWD\n\[\e[m\]\[\e[0;33m\]$git_branch\[\e[m\]\[$txtred\]$git_dirty\[$txtrst\]$ '
```

The prompt will now hopefully expand to sth like this if you are on a git branch

[image]

Comment: If you use `$PWD` instead of `$(pwd)` the shell doesn't have to set up a pipe, fork two new processes and invoke one external command for every prompt. Also, you don't need to export `PS1` and it's probably better if you don't. :-)

Comment: @DavidFoerster thanks! I have updated my answer accordingly.