# Reverse-search in CLI: messed up output afterwards

Tags: command-line, bashrc, ps1

**See my edit below, this is not totally a duplicate of [Shell prompt customization and cmd behavior](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908679/shell-prompt-customization-and-cmd-behavior)**

My `reverse-search` function in the CLI is broken and I don't know how to fix it back...

When I hit ctrl+r and search a command I did earlier, find it then press the right arrow key to use it, the output is broken. Here is an example:

```
# I reverse-searched the word "test" then pressed right arrow
yoshiji@x1carbon:~/path/to/git/folder (master) $ch)`test': rake test
#                                              ^^^^^^^^^^ weird output
#                                                     ^ cursor right there
```

It also "shifts" my cursor to a different position. If I press enter, the right command is executed (`rake test` in this case) so it means the text displayed is not the same as what is actually executed.

I know this is most-likely related to my `PS1` export in my `~/.bashrc`, so here are the last lines of this file:

```
# Git branch in prompt.
git_branch() {
  branch=$(__git_ps1 2> /dev/null)
  if [ "$branch" = " (master)" ]; then
     echo -e "\033[33m${branch}\033[00m" # yellow
  elif [ "$branch" = "" ]; then
     echo -e "\033[90m (no git)\033[00m" # red
  else
     echo -e "\033[32m${branch}\033[00m" # green
  fi
}
PS1='\u@\h:\w$(git_branch) \$ '
```

This is something I wrote to displays the git branch in orange (if `master` branch) or else in green (or `no git` in gray).

Do you guys have any idea on what is causing this weird behavior?

---

**Edit:** This is a different problem from the [possible duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908679/shell-prompt-customization-and-cmd-behavior) in the way that I am using `echo -e "some string"` to return a string having color+name of the git branch from the function `git_branch()`. Using `echo -e` does not escape the characters `\[` and `\]` (try it yourself in your CLI: `echo -e "\[\033[33m\]test"`).

Ideally, I would like to keep those conditional colors based on the branch's presence & name (gray if no branch, orange if master, else green).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wrap the color sequences in readline escapes like so:

```
echo -e "\001\033[33m\002${branch}\001\033[00m\002" # yellow
echo -e "\001\033[90m\002 (no git)\001\033[00m\002" # red
echo -e "\001\033[32m\002${branch}\001\033[00m\002" # green
```

The readline escapes are `\001` at the start of a non-printing sequence, and `\002` at the end. These are equivalent to `\[` and `\]`, respectively, in the PS1 string.

Source: [archemiro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43462720/4518341) on [bash prompt and echoing colors inside a function - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6592077/4518341)

---

*This is [my answer from another question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1018099/301745) with the code changed.*

Answer (score 4):

When you put colour codes in your prompt you have to add extra markers to let the terminal know that you have invisible characters in the prompt

Change

```sh
 echo -e "\033[33m${branch}\033[00m" # yellow
```

to

```sh
 echo -e "\[\033[33m\]${branch}\[\033[00m\]" # yellow
 # .......^^........^^.........^^........^^
```

and so on

See [Controlling the Prompt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt) in the bash manual.

Comment: I did this but it does not escape, it just adds the `\[` and `\]` to the final result: `\[\] (master)\[\] $`. I think this is because I use `echo` to output the string then capture it via a call to the function in the PS1 assignment...

Comment: After further investigation, it is in fact the use of `echo -e` that prints out the `\[` and `\]` that should be escaped for the PS1...

Comment: You could ignore the `\[` and `\]` and add a newline before the `\$`, then the "weird output" problem won't bother you anymore -- that's what I do, but I like the `$` at the left of the screen anyway.